# Google Drives API - retrieve files owned by me

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the Google Drives API, how do I formulate Q when retrieving the file listing, to only get back files that are owned by me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the files that you are the owner using the method of "Files: list" in Drive API.
- You want to create the search query for achieving this.

For this, how about this answer?

In this case, you can create the search query using `owners` in the fields.

#### Sample search query:

```
'me' in owners
```

If you want to retrieve the files in the specific folder, you can use the following search query.

```
'###' in parents and 'me' in owners
```

#### Sample curl:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27me%27%20in%20owners&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

and

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27%23%23%23%27%20in%20parents%20and%20%27me%27%20in%20owners&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the folder without publicly sharing, please use the access token instead of the API key. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)